# Horizontal list items not in line

Tags: html, css, list

Can anyone tell me why 3 of my list items are not aligned with the first list item?

The vertical descrepancy seems to vary from browser to browser.

Full code and css here: http://tinkerbin.com/sPPwMctY

Comment: I'm not able to view your list at all. They appear as invisible to me (verified on Firefox, Safari and on Chrome)

Comment: Please make sure your examples show the problem clearly.

Comment: are you talking about the list of select boxes?

Comment: I have replicated this as well as I can on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sPGLE/) for anyone who is more comfortable with that

Comment: And please reduce the example to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) -- there's probably lots of stuff in there right now that only serves to distract.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `margin-top: 0;` for the radio buttons next to your second and third `select` boxes.

Check this **demo**: http://tinkerbin.com/3Kgy5SjV

Answer (score 0):

By doing Some changes in your css it is now cross browser.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/89I0GPcX)

ADDED/UPDATED FOLLOWING:

```
.select_style {
    height:23px;
    line-height:23px;
}

.junior_rank #one  {
    position:relative;
    width:753px;
    left: 118px;
        /*Removed top property*/    
}

#groupranking_label {
    position: relative;
    left: 23px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 17px; /*updated*/
}
```